# Select 50 rows, but only up to 10 with same column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, select

We're running SQL Server 2016. I'm currently building a table that will hold employee data for various companies we have dealings with.  The table will be populated with employee information for the various companies in the form of:

| Name | Company | Status | DateTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Person 01 | Company1 |  | 11/08/2021 07:01:00.00 |
| Person 02 | Company1 |  | 11/08/2021 07:02:00.00 |
| Person 03 | Company1 |  | 11/08/2021 07:03:00.00 |
| Person 04 | Company1 |  | 11/08/2021 07:04:00.00 |
| Person 05 | Company1 |  | 11/08/2021 07:05:00.00 |
| Person 06 | Company1 |  | 11/08/2021 07:06:00.00 |
| Person 07 | Company1 |  | 11/08/2021 07:07:00.00 |
| Person 08 | Company1 |  | 11/08/2021 07:08:00.00 |
| Person 09 | Company1 |  | 11/08/2021 07:09:00.00 |
| Person 10 | Company1 |  | 11/08/2021 07:10:00.00 |
| Person 11 | Company1 |  | 11/08/2021 07:11:00.00 |
| Person 12 | Company1 |  | 11/08/2021 07:12:00.00 |
| Person 13 | Company2 |  | 11/08/2021 07:13:00.00 |
| Person 14 | Company2 |  | 11/08/2021 07:14:00.00 |
| Person 15 | Company2 |  | 11/08/2021 07:15:00.00 |
| Person 16 | Company2 |  | 11/08/2021 07:16:00.00 |

We'll have a lot more data than that, but what we're trying to achieve is, every day, we want to do a selection of the first 50 with a blank status, and group these together.

Once we finish with them for the day, the Status is updated so we can select the next 50 easily.

This part is easy, however, the bit I'm unsure about is that we only want to select up to 10 entries from the same company every day.

For example, we want to retrieve 50 results, but only up to 10 can have the same company.

The 50 results may look like:

- 10 from Company 1
- 10 from Company 2
- 8 from Company 3 (since they didn't submit 8 or they did them later, so their no longer next in line)
- 2 from Company 4
- 10 from Company 5
- 10 from Company 6

I've gotten this far, but I don't know how to only select up to 10 from each company:

```
select top 50 *
from EmployeeData
where insull(Status,'') <> ''
order by DateTime
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Luke

Comment: I will advise you to use a stored procedure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this maybe:

```
select top 50 [Name], [Company], [Status], [DateTime]
from (
    SELECT [Name], [Company], [Status], [DateTime],
    ROW_NUMBER ( ) OVER ( PARTITION BY [Company] order by [Name] ) rownum
    FROM EmployeeData
    where insull(Status,'') <> ''
) tbl
where rownum <= 10
order by [DateTime]
```

Comment: This idea is correct. I think you need to change `FROM EmployeeData` to `FROM (select top 50 * from EmployeeData where  isnull(Status,'') <> '' order by DateTime) t` because @ValiantSirDK asked after getting 50 rows.

Comment: Thats true. Its updated now. I added the top 50 on the outer level though. Adding the 50 limit on the inner query could end up selecting 50 of one company, then limiting it further to 10 with no other companies listed

Comment: Maybe user want smaller count of company. If total row of each company is 15, user experience can be good to do 15 at once for one company than do 10 at first time, 5 at next time.

Comment: Thanks Kristian.  This was simple to use and exactly what I needed.  Thanks for the support.

Answer (score 1):

This query has two CTE's.  First, the unique Company names are selected as 'unq_cte'.  Second, 10 random rows are selected for each company as 'all_cte'.  Last, from the 'all_cte' (collection of maximum 10 rows per company) the query selects 50 rows at random.

```
;with
unq_cte as (
    select distinct Company
    from EmployeeData),
all_cte as (
    select top10.*
    from unq_cte uc
         cross apply (select top(10) *
                      from EmployeeData ed
                      where uc.Company=ed.Company
                      order by newid()) 
                      top10([Name], Company, [Status], [DateTime]))
select top(50) *
from all_cte
order by newid();
```

Comment: This selects top 10 for each company first, top 50 after. I don't know this step is fit to ValiantSirDK. But selecting top 10 first will be different with top 50 first.